# Calculate the group $\mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I'm trying to calculate the group $\mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m$.
I'm really bad with groups so I'd appreciate a verification of my conclusion:

If $m$ is even then $\forall x\in \mathbb Z_m$ we get $2x\bmod m$ is even and therefore
$$\mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m=\{x\in\mathbb Z_m \mid 2=0\}=\mathbb Z_2.$$

If $m$ is odd then $2\cdot (m+1)/2 \bmod m=1$ and therefore $2\mathbb Z_m=\mathbb Z_m$ so we get $\mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m=0$.

Am I right?

Comment: The proper notation for a quotient is $\large G/H$, not $\dfrac{G}{H}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deductions are correct.

Here's a different approach: since $\Bbb Z_m=\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ we have
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z_m}{2\Bbb Z_m}\simeq\frac{\Bbb Z}{(2,m)}.
$$
Now $(2,m)={\Bbb Z}m$ if $m$ is $2\mid m$ and $(2,m)={\Bbb Z}$ if $m$ is odd, yielding the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but the details are not really convincing: $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_m\mid 2=0\}$ doesn't seem meaningful.

If $m$ is odd, then your proof that $2\mathbb{Z}_m=\mathbb{Z}_m$ is essentially good:
$$
x=2(nx)
$$
where $n=(m+1)/2$.

Let $m$ be even. The map $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}_m\to 2\mathbb{Z}_m$ defined by $x\mapsto 2x$ is surjective and its kernel is $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_m\mid 2x=0\}$ which has two elements. Thus $|\mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m|=2$.

Another way is to recall the general homomorphism theorem:
$$
\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\Big/2\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
\cong
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}
$$
when, of course, $2\mathbb{Z}\supseteq m\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is correct, although I'd be careful when writing $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_m\vert 2=0\}$. I know what you mean by this, but really this is the set of $x\in\mathbb{Z}_m$ such that $2=0$, which is the empty set. Personally I would write something like $\{x(\text{mod }2) \vert x\in\mathbb{Z}_m\}$, although to do this one should really rigorously define mod in $\mathbb{Z}_m$. Also, when you say 'calculate the group', we are really only doing this up to isomorphism, as really $\mathbb{Z}_2\neq \mathbb{Z}_m/2\mathbb{Z}_m$, as the elements of the former are $\{0,1\}$, whilst the latter is $\{0+2\mathbb{Z}_m,1+2\mathbb{Z}_m\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a very similar question: suppose $G = C_m$, a cyclic group of order $m$, with generator $a$. What is $G/\langle a^2\rangle$?

Well, the order of $a^2$ is $\dfrac{m}{\gcd(2,m)}$.

If $m$ is even, then the gcd in the denominator is $2$, and $a^2$ (and thus $\langle a^2\rangle$) has order $\dfrac{m}{2}$.

Since $|G/H| = \dfrac{|G|}{|H|}$, we see in this case that $G/\langle a^2\rangle$ has order $2$ (so we must have just two cosets: $\langle a^2\rangle$ and $a\langle a^2 \rangle$). This is, of course, isomorphic to $C_2$, as every group of order $2$ is.

If $m$ is odd, then the gcd is $1$, and thus $a^2$ has order $m$, so generates $G$, in which case $G/\langle a^2\rangle$ is trivial.